# Can I setup variables in def __init__ that are not passed into def __init__?

Tags: python

Is it ok to set attributes in "def init" that are not passed to the function? Like this code below--only the env is passed in. But I would like the functions in the class to know about local_gdb and reference_data.

class specs:

```
def __init__(self, env):
    self.env = env
    local_gdb = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "Clip.gdb")
    self.local_gdb = local_gdb
    self.reference_data = {
        'moa_centerline': {'sde': 'MOAADM.Addressing_DBO_STREETS\MOAADM.streets',
                           'gdb': os.path.join(local_gdb, 'MOA_Streets')},
        'moa_address': {'sde': 'MOAADM.ADDRESS_POINT',
                        'gdb': os.path.join(local_gdb, 'MOA_Address')},
        'kpb_address': {'sde': "KPBADM.PhysicalAddress",
                        'gdb': os.path.join(local_gdb, "KPB_Address")},
    }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be ok? Does the code work?

Comment: Do you mean `__init__`???

Comment: Those extra attributes look like they're going to be exactly the same for every instance of your class - in which case they probably belong in the class body (thus producing *class attributes*), rather than uselessly recalculating them every time the class is instantiated.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Yes, it works fine. I am just wondering from a style point of view. Is this an accepted pattern.

Comment: @John, yes sorry I will fix it

Comment: Of course, many many times you'll have to initialize some instance status for internal use, things the user not necessarily have to provide as arguments. In fact, the fewer arguments your class receive, the better, as well it keeps its functionality and flexibility.

Comment: Yes, the attributes can be set to other values. For example, you have a class for human, you probably want to initialize the attributes arms=2, legs=2. No need to require input values for these, though you can.

Comment: To answer the question: yes.

Comment: Bringing up your instance to a usable state (i.e. initializing) is the whole point of `__init__()`. You'd typically initialize the whole internal state of your instance in it whether the internal state is based on externally provided arguments or not.

Comment: The `__init__()` method is the preferred location for defining instance variables, perhaps even setting default values for unspecified attributes. Consider using keyword args in the `__init__()`.

Comment: @jasonharper - did some reading on class attributes. I think this is what I need.

Comment: @chepner - so, the local gdb will end up having the same value every time

Comment: @fallingdog oops, I didn't look carefully enough, and assumed `local_gdb` was an argument to `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

I refactored the top of class spec to be:

```
local_gdb = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "Clip.gdb")
reference_data = {
    'moa_centerline': {'sde': 'MOAADM.Addressing_DBO_STREETS\MOAADM.streets',
                       'gdb': os.path.join(local_gdb, 'MOA_Streets')},
    'moa_address': {'sde': 'MOAADM.ADDRESS_POINT',
                    'gdb': os.path.join(local_gdb, 'MOA_Address')},
    'kpb_address': {'sde': "KPBADM.PhysicalAddress",
                    'gdb': os.path.join(local_gdb, "KPB_Address")},
}

def __init__(self, env):
    self.env = env
```